# java:how to store values of dynamically generated textfields

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans-7

I have generated textfields dynamically. How many textfields are generated the number given by user. After generating textfields user goin to insert name and contact number into textfields. So my question is how to store these values into database. I am using Mysql. I know getText() method, but how to use it? Here is the code of dynamically generated textfields.

```
private void Extra()
{   
if(no_of_people.getText().equals(" "))
{
    String st="The entry 'Number of People' should not be blank.";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,st);
}    
try
{
String nop=(no_of_people.getText().toString());
int nop1 = Integer.parseInt(nop.trim());
int j=nop1;

Extra_people extrpeo=new Extra_people();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
extrpeo.setSize(450,500);
extrpeo.setVisible(true);
extrpeo.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
extrpeo.add(panel);
extrpeo.validate();
Vector textFieldVector = new Vector();
JLabel lb1,lb2;
JTextField tf,tf1;
int i=1;
while (i <= nop1) 
{
    lb1=new JLabel("Name "+i);
    panel.add(lb1);
    tf = new JTextField(10);
    textFieldVector.add(tf);
    panel.add(tf);
    //String value = tf.getText();
    lb2=new JLabel("Contact Number "+i);
    panel.add(lb2);
    tf1 = new JTextField(10);
    textFieldVector.add(tf1);
    panel.add(tf1);
    i++;
    }
    panel.validate();
    panel.repaint();
    }    
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(" "+e);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the references to all the `JTextField`s into an `List<JTextField>`, then from there you will be able to access them just by iterating through the list.

You will need two variables like these -

```
List<JTextField> yourArrayListForName = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
List<JTextField> yourArrayListForContact = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
```

Then, modify your `while` loop -

```
while (i <= nop1) 
{
    lb1=new JLabel("Name "+i);
    panel.add(lb1);

    tf = new JTextField(10);
    textFieldVector.add(tf);
    panel.add(tf);
    yourArrayListForName.add(tf);        // add this line

    //String value = tf.getText();
    lb2=new JLabel("Contact Number "+i);
    panel.add(lb2);

    tf1 = new JTextField(10);
    textFieldVector.add(tf1);
    panel.add(tf1);
    yourArrayListForContact.add(tf1);        // add this line

    i++;
}
```

Then, when you need to access those values, use something like below -

```
for(JTextField field : yourArrayListForName)
{
    field.getText();     // input will be obtained here
}

for(JTextField field : yourArrayListForContact)
{
    field.getText();     // input will be obtained here
}
```

Comment: I tried this code It cant return the value of Textfield by using the method for(JTextField field : yourArrayListForName)
{
    field.getText();     // input will be obtained here
}

Answer (score 0):

Get the string in the text field by calling yourTextField.getText() method whenever you need it.

```
String x = yourInputField.getText();
```

Attach an action listener to the text field. It is called whenever the user types Enter in that field. The listener can then write information to DB.

Comment: I am using netbeans 7. The textfields are generated dynamically, so i am not getting input field name. Thatswhy I am anable to use getText() method. :(

Comment: but you have tf and tf1 which has the getText() methode, did i miss anything?

Comment: @ O.D- I have tried tf.getText() and tf1.getText(), but its printing 'JTextfield1.getText()' instead of textfield's value.

Comment: Strange! well happy debugging dude. Set aq breakpoint to check the values of GetText() into the loop, and after.

Answer (score 0):

In your event listener method, you could loop through the `JPanel` for all `TextField`s within it.

```
for (Component c : panel1.getComponents()) {
    if (c instanceof JTextField) { 
       JTextField textField = ((JTextField)c);
       String name;
       String contact;
       if(textField.getName().startsWith("Name") {
           // Name field
           name = textField.getText();
       } else {
           // Contact field
           contact = textField.getText();

       }
       // Validate and persist.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handel the textFields with an array, then you have to able these:
Get the string from textField like this:

```
str[i] = textField[i].getText();
```

but you have to define the string array first:

```
String[] str[] = new String[nop1]();
```

then store them into database.